# Firefox on Ubuntu can't connect to local virtualhost when network is unplugged

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, localhost, virtual-host

I'm using Firefox (3.6.17) on my Ubuntu Lucid (rel. 10.04) and noticed that if the network cable is plugged everything is fine and I'm able to browse my local virtualhost configured in Apache2.

But if I unplug the network, the local vhost is no longer reachable by Firefox and shows the message:

> Server not found
>   Firefox can't find the server at atn-dev.hal901.com

I think Linux and Apache2 are configured correctly because wget and Chromium browser are still able to contact the vhost. It seems to be a Firefox bug.

The problem is I widely use Firefox and I need it for web development.  Firefox is only able to reach `http://localhost/` when network is unplugged.

I know there is the Firefox *"Work Offline"* option in the File  menu, but I already unchecked it.
  Moreover I completely disabled it through the `about:config` page, setting `browser.offline` property to `false`.

Can anyone figure out a solution?

Comment: How does the host get resolved ? local DNS ? or hosts file ?

Comment: @dvhh the name is resolved trough hosts file.

Comment: Is the virtual host on the same subnet as the machine itself?

Comment: @normalocity: my machine is hal901.com (IP:127.0.0.1 netmsk: 255.0.0.0) and vhost is atn-dev.hal901.com (IP:127.0.1.1). Not sure this answer your question

Comment: With those settings, shouldn't your netmask be for a Class C address (i.e. 255.255.255.0)? Out of curiosity, try changing that and let me know if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try going to `about:config`, and search for `network.dns.disableIPv6`. Set this to `false`, and then see if network name resolution works.

[This](http://tristram.squarespace.com/home/2011/6/3/firefox-ignoring-etchosts-when-dns-not-available.html) person seemed to be having the same issue as you are, and was able to fix it by using that.

Comment: **FANTASTIC** your suggestion solved my problem!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks - this fix is still relevant with Firefox 18 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This did the trick in my Linuxmint 15 machine with Firefox 23.

Comment: There is a bug for this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267257

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that it is unable to resolve `atn-dev.hal901.com` when the cable is unplugged, and the other browsers are caching the DNS result from previous lookups. Have you tried adding the domain to your `/etc/hosts` file?
`sudo echo "127.0.0.1    atn-dev.hal901.com" >> /etc/hosts`

Your other solution would be the assign a `ServerPath` to the vhost, such as adding the `ServerPath /atn-dev` directive to the configuration (usually just below the `ServerName` directive). You could then access the vhost at `http://127.0.0.0/atn-dev/`

Comment: Thank ou for answer, I alrerady have that line in /etc/hosts. I must say that everything was fine some times ago. Then I changed something (don't know exactly what, maybe a temporary static IP configuration in NetworkManager instead of DHCP) and now FF can't resolve the name any more.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on Xubuntu 14.04 / Firefox 30.0, and I'm still having the same problem. the suggested fix, setting `network.dns.disableIPv6` to `false`, didn't work for me. While I'd still like to have this fixed in another way (comments welcome), a workaround is to put Firefox into **offline mode**.

Comment: This is not an actual answer to the author's problem.  Please don't submit, comments that indicate an answer does not work, as an answer to questions.